# Expressing unitary operator of time as a matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation

Can someone please show the full calculation if we were to experess
[image] as a unitary matrix

Comment: It is written as a unitary matrix already if your Hamiltonian is hermitian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to ask is how to write out the matrix elements of $U$ because it is already unitary. The exponential $\exp{A}$ of any matrix $A$ is simply

\begin{equation}
\exp{A}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}=\text{id}+A+\frac{A^2}{2}+...
\end{equation}

If you know how to express powers of matrices, then the rest should follow smoothly. Simply substitute $A=iHt$.